# How do I add a scoring system to my python game that deducts points when I am wrong and gives me points when I am right

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been working on this project for the past 2 days and I am nearly finished but I would really like to add a working scoring system but I couldn't find any answers on google. Pls Send Help.

```
import random

score = 0

def main():

    bet = input("Place Your Bet On A Number From 1-10 (quit to exit): ")

    number = random.randint(1, 10)
    
    if(bet == number):

        global score
        score+=1
        print("Correct!, ", score)
        print(" ")


    else:
        score-=1
        print("Incorrect!, ", score)
        print(" ")
        print("Your Bet: ", bet)
        print("The ACTUAL number: ", number)
        print(" ")

    if(bet == "quit"):
        exit()

while True:
    main()
```

I tried adding a scoring system to my game but it kept deducting points even though I was right. I searched on google but all of the answers were outdated and didn't work on my program.

Comment: when you take input with `input()` it returns variable of type `str`. `random.randint(1,10)` returns variable of type `int`. So you need to either convert your `number` to `str` with something like `number = str(number)` or `bet` to integer with `bet = int(bet)`

Comment: Bro thank you so much! I have been searching everywhere for the answer.